# Retrieve Custom Binding Parameters in Provider Ninject

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, dependency-injection, ninject

Hi I am using `Ninject` in a `Xamarin` `MVVM` project. What I am trying to do is to bind specific implementations based on a enum type:

```
var foo = new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("type", VMType, true);
Kernel.Get<ICommonComponentVM>(foo);
```

and the provider:

```
public class ICommonComponentVMProvider : Provider<ICommonComponentVM>
{
    protected override ICommonComponentVM CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
         //return the implementation based on type
    }
}
```

which is binded in the Kernel Module as:

```
public class CoreModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ICommonComponentVM>().ToProvider<ICommonComponentVMProvider>();
    }
}
```

How can I extract the custom parameter from the binding `IContext`?
Or is this the correct way to do this? The [Ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki) lacks this info.

**EDIT**

I arrived at

```
var param = context.Parameters.Single((arg) => arg.Name == "type");
```

but accessing the value of the parameter with `param.GetValue` needs two arguments: `IContext` and `ITarget`. I have the `context` but what should I put as `Target`?

In the meantime it works with `null`:

```
var type = (CommonVMTypes)param.GetValue(context, null);
```

so it looks like this:

```
protected override ICommonComponentVM CreateInstance(IContext context)
{
    var param = context.Parameters.Single((arg) => arg.Name == "type");
    if (param == null){
        return null;
    }
    var type = (CommonVMTypes)param.GetValue(context, null); //<-- Needs an Action ITarget

    switch (type)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the parameters by the property `ICollection<IParameter> IContext.Parameters`. You can find it by using `context.Parameters.Single(x => x.Name == "type")`.

You could also subclass `Parameter` or implement `IParameter` for a custom parameter type with strongly typed information, p.Ex. `ComponentVMTypeParameter` and then select it using `context.Parameters.OfType<ComponentVMTypeParameter>().Single()`.

Alternative approaches:

- use conditional bindings (`When(...)` syntax, can check for parameters, too) instead of the providers. Does not require extending the provider.
- use a [factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) instead of a provider.
- using named bindings:

  - `Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().Named("Foo1")`
  - `IResolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>("Foo1");`

However, in principle there's no need to use an `IProvider`. You could instead

However, if there's a limited amount of types I'd consider using an abstract factory instead

Comment: thank you, I arrived at the first part of your solution. please see my edit. I need the last part. Anyway I am accepting your answer

Comment: Regarding `Factory`, I would anyway instantiate the `ViewModels` with `Kernel.Get<ViewModel>()` because of the dependencies wired on them.

Comment: @Sanandrea `var type = (CommonVMTypes)param.GetValue(context, null);` is ok. The implementation does not require the target to have any value. The way you use it, even the `context` is not being accessed. The `Parameter` class is very generic and allows lots of use cases.